# Advanced Custom Fields (acf) - Filter Relationship by Taxonomies not Post Type

Tags: plugins, filters, woocommerce-offtopic, advanced-custom-fields

I have a Field Group looks like this:

[image: Field order]

And I can only filter with Post type which is bad to me at the moment because Woocommerce using only product as Post type:

[image: Only Post Type available]

And when I make a post I only see this:

[image: Filter by products]

Is there any way to make that filter to Taxonomies and make a filter by selected Taxonomies?

Comment: ACF is third party plugin. it's completely off-topic here. please ask respected plugin support panel/forum. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Under "Field Type" you can select "Taxonomy". Then once that type is selected you should see additional options to select the taxonomy you want to use, and also the field type you would like to use for selecting them (checkbox, radio button, etc.):

[image: ACF Taxonomy]

Comment: I need the relationship category.